# Why does my Terminal window close automatically?

Tags: macos, terminal, unix

I need to use my Terminal window on a MacBook Air but it closes about 10 seconds after I open it.  Is there a setting or is it possible another program is causing it to close?  If I type quickly I can run say diskutil but it closes after it runs.

Comment: It sounds like terminal is crashing.
Can you open console app and look for error messages which might be related to the problem?

Comment: Maybe your .profile or .bashrc is corrupted. Can you use a different account on your Mac, open Terminal.app from there and ssh to your account?

Comment: Since you get a prompt, it's likely a resource limit is killing the newly launched processes. Have you confirmed this happens after a reboot? Also - a new user account would be a quick way to rule out any settings on your account.

Comment: Is Terminal quitting or is it still open when the window closes? If Terminal is gone, it sounds like it must be a crash, in which case there should be a crash log for it. If it's just the window that closes, it sounds like something is causing the shell to exit. By default Terminal won't close a window when the shell exits, but you may have customized the preference to do so. Make sure **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Shell > When the shell exits** is set to **Don't close the window**. That will help narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: Fire up `Console` and see if you find something about Terminal crashing.

Comment: As a method to see whether this is an issue with Terminal.app or some `.profile` or `.bashrc` file, try to reproduce the issue with [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com). IMHO it's the better terminal app anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a system administrator that has blocked terminal, you should get permission from your system administrator to unblock it.